# How to create a list item with an icon on the left, center and right?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating a ionic app that uses the Spotify API. I want to create a widget that is a list item with an icon on the left(last-song), center(play/pause) and right(next-song) icons. I'm having trouble creating a list item with the three icons. Here is my code...

```
<div class="list card">
  <div class="item item-icon-left item-icon-center item-icon-right">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-rewind"></i>
    <i class="icon ion-play"></i>
    <i class="icon ion-ios-fastfoward"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with what exactly you have?

Comment: what's wrong with your "code"? What do you expect to see? What do you see instead?

Comment: The first two icons stack on top of each other while the last one is hidden. What I expected to see was the first icon float left, second to be centered and the third to float to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :)

```
<div class="list card">
  <div class="item item-icon-left item-icon-center item-icon-right">
    <p style="float: left; width: 34%; text-align: left;">last</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center;">play/pause</p>
    <p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: right;">next</p>
  </div>
</div>
```